# AzerothCore build error: charconv file not found

Tags: azerothcore

On Ubuntu 18.04 tried both using clang 6 and clang 10, AzerothCore fails to build:

[image: azerothcore error]

Answer (score 1):

solution by **polly**

update to latest clang and cmake, also install gcc-10

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install gcc-10 g++-10
```